# Printing block on all pages of a contenttype

Tags: theming, blocks

In my page--front.tpl.php i have a menu block rendered using:

```
<?php
$block = block_load('menu', 'menu-basic-menu');
print render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
?>
```

Which works as expected.

What should i do to print this block on all pages of a specific content type?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print my block per content type i used following code in my template file:

```
<?php
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
  // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "page--blog.tpl.php".
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $vars['node']->type);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can created the `page.tpl.php` and put a condition to check the content type then print this block.

[page.tpl.php API Drupal 7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7)

From node object you can find the content type to check condition.

```
<?php print_r($node);?>
```

More specific to your question.

```
<?php global $node;
    if ( isset($node) && !empty($node) && $node->type == 'type_name') {

            $block = block_load('menu', 'menu-basic-menu');
            print render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I'd go for this solution too.

Comment: thanks
The block is rendering fine. However i am getting an:
"Notice: Undefined variable: node in include() (line 79 of C:....."  Still working on my php skills..

Comment: once try for global $node;

Comment: Using:

      `<?php global $node; print_r($node);?>
       <?php if ( !empty($node) && $node->type == 'page') {     $block = block_load('superfish', '1');
        print render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); }  ?>`

The error is gone however the block doen't render anymore. Sorry for the markup

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Why to alter page.tpl when the block it self can be restricted to certain content types?

Comment: Tried the code but no luck. No errors but no block as well.
The block functions as a menu and should have images (in a page) as a background.

Comment: Have you checked "admin/structure/block"?.Able to see the block?

Comment: yes its configurable at block/manage/superfish/1/configure

Comment: Then you need not go for a long process. You can easily do. Click on configure set the region and visible settings('choose content type').

Comment: Is this work for you?

Comment: Not really. Using this method makes my block appear beside my node. Instead i want my block appear at front, using my node as a background.

Comment: Just tried but now that i am using a template file block configurations cannot be applied  as it seems.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20295/discussion-between-smalution-and-user25765).